# Is there a way to generate multiople GitLab CI/CD yml files which are then deployed by a job

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create a pipeline like in the diagram:

[image: Pipeline Diagram]

I have a job which generates a pipeline with a template, this is saved as an artifact. Then the deployment job has a trigger which runs it whenever it receives the artefacts file `deploy-pipeline.yml` which then creates the downstream pipeline. However, I now need to be able to generate multiple files which are all picked up and generated as downstream pipelines, is this possible?

Edit: Final solution described by @sytech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [dynamic child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) for this purpose. It sounds like that may be what you're doing already.

You can do this with multiple files just by adding more trigger jobs.

```yaml
generate-pipelines:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - echo "you implement this"
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - pipeline1.yml
    - pipeline2.yml
    # ... etc.

downstream 1:
  trigger:
    include:
      - job: generate-pipelines
        artifact: pipeline1.yml

downstream 2:
  trigger:
    include:
      - job: generate-pipelines
        artifact: pipeline2.yml
# etc..
```

---

If you want to do this dynamically for any arbitrary number of files, you can have your pipeline generate another pipeline that has all the downstream triggers dynamically.

source-pipeline.yml

```yaml
generate-pipeline-generator:
  stage: .pre
  script:
  - echo 'generate a child pipeline with N trigger jobs for each file'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generate-pipelines.yml

pipeline-generator-trigger:
  trigger:
    include:
      - job: generate-pipelines.yml
        artifact: generate-pipelines.yml
```

The contents of `generate-pipelines.yml` would look similar to the first yaml described in this answer, but all the artifact paths and downstream trigger jobs would be generated dynamically by the source pipeline.
The final effect would be 1 source pipeline that produces 1 child pipeline that in turn generates *N* nested child pipelines.

Comment: Would there be a way to dynamically add pipeline yml files without having to declare them? So if I had 2 files generated in one pipeline but 3 in another. Similarly, could they also be dynamically triggered without specifying individual downstream pipelines.

Comment: I was able to use wildcards when generating the files but currently it does not seem possible to use a wildcard in a job trigger/include. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/331313

Comment: @ChrisDworczyk you _might_ be able to arrange this in such a way that it can be done dynamically for any number of downstream pipelines, but I think you would need an intermediate dynamic pipeline. That is: the source pipeline generates a first child pipeline containing a trigger job for each file generated, which in turn generates the _n_ nested child pipelines.

Comment: That's the approach I went with in the end. So in addition to generating the pipelineN.yml files I also generate the `intermediate dynamic pipeline` which has its trigger/include sections filled in with the explicit file paths to all the pipelineN.yml files. I then have a job that triggers once the dynamic pipeline file is crated which contains all the downstream pipelines...bit convoluted but works for now.